# Master Detail Application not loading UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am creating an iPad version of Master Detail Application using XCode 4.5 with ARC. I have my iPadMaster.h/.m(as my master) and iPadDetailViewController.h/m(as my detail) set up.

I am trying to load different view controllers from iPadDetailViewController when users click/select the rows on iPadMaster.

On iPadDetailController.h, i set this:

```
@property int itemNumber;
```

On iPadMaster.h, i called it as:

```
@class iPadDetailViewController;
```

and proceeded with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController * DVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    DVC.itemNumber = indexPath.row;
}
```

On iPadDetailViewController, i set this:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    switch (_itemNumber) {
        case 1:
        {
            iPadLogin *next = [[iPadLogin alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *mut = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            mut = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
            [mut replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:next];
            self.splitViewController.viewControllers = mut;
            break;
        }

        default:{
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
            break;
    }
}

//then i called it on:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];

}
```

When i clicked the second row in the master table, item_number should be 1 and load the 'iPadLogin' but nothing happens... Any pointers is much appreciated...

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Why not just change the detail controller from the master? Just put your switch statement in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, and use switch(indexPath.row)

Comment: @rdelmar for iPad version?

Comment: You can either modify the detailviewcontroller so that it reloads data into itself, or replace the detailviewcontroller with a new one with the new data. What you're doing is some of both...

Comment: I'vee been doing it for iPhone all along. This is the first attempt for iPad. And i'm following it from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713478/master-detail-application-for-ipad/15713674?noredirect=1#comment22333347_15713674). I would have amended the original post there but some users advised against ding that... If its not too much to ask, can you post a sample i can rely on at your convenience... Thank you...

Comment: Why not for iPad? It seems to me that the master controller should be doing the change. Normally, when you pick a row in a table, it is that controller which instantiates the detail controller and pushes to it (on iPhone), so why not use the master to change the detail?

Comment: do you have a sample code i can work on to do it on the master table controller to load split view from `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`... Really appreciate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I think you should change the detail controller from the master controller. It is in the master that you're making the decision on what detail controller to go to (by picking a row in the table), so it should be the responsibility of the master controller to make the change. The code below should do that (note, however, if you're using a storyboard for your controllers, then you should be using [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"whatever"] to get your next controller rather than alloc init).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 1:
            {
                iPadLogin *next = [[iPadLogin alloc] init];
                NSMutableArray *mut = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                mut = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
                [mut replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:next];
                self.splitViewController.viewControllers = mut;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                AnotherVC *another = [[AnotherVC alloc] init];
                NSMutableArray *mut = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                mut = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
                [mut replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:another];
                self.splitViewController.viewControllers = mut;
                break;
            }

            default:{
                UIViewController *detail = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];
                detail.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did that yesterday based on your hints but there was a problem. When i clicked at any of the rows, it loads the view controller. The loaded view controllers did not have any navigation bar thus obscuring the menu or the tableview of the master file. Therefore it just freezes at the first view controller selected...

Comment: Your solution is the best and most logical if only i could get around the missing navigation bar which should allow the menu to pop up again...

Comment: @TeamStar, well, that's another question. If my post answered your question, you should accept it.